# mysql inserting into table with select and another value

Tags: mysql, insert

I was wondering how you would insert into a table from an existing table.

I'm trying to get all the information from the student table and if they have x amount of credits they are now an instructor with $10000 salary.

```
INSERT into instructor
(SELECT * FROM student HAVING student.tot_cred > 100 AND student.dept_name = instructor.dept_name)
```

I think I have the first part down, but I'm not sure on how to enter the salary.

#### student

```
ID  varchar(5)  PRI
name    varchar(20) 
dept_name   varchar(20) MUL
tot_cred    decimal(3,0)
```

#### instructor

```
ID  varchar(5)  PRI
name    varchar(20) 
dept_name   varchar(20) MUL
salary  decimal(8,2)
```

Never mind I was able to get it using this:

```
INSERT into instructor (name, ID, dept_name, salary)
SELECT name, ID, dept_name, 10000
FROM student
WHERE student.tot_cred > 100 AND student.dept_name = dept_name;
```

Comment: Please share the table structure.

Comment: oh sorry, yeah give me a sec

Comment: It's good that you solved the problem on your own. You can post it as an answer instead.

Comment: oh, I forgot that I can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you used `student.dept_name = instructor.dept_name` in your query. The following will work.

```
INSERT
    INTO
        instructor(`name`, `dept_name`, `salary`)
        SELECT `name`, `dept_name`, 10000
            FROM student
            WHERE total_cred > 100 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

`INSERT into instructor (name, ID, dept_name, salary)
SELECT name, ID, dept_name, 10000
FROM student
WHERE student.tot_cred > 100 AND student.dept_name = dept_name;`

Comment: Your solution is wrong. You can not reference the table you're inserting into and it also doesn't make sense. Insert creates new rows, there's nothing to reference. Update on the other hand...This `...AND student.dept_name = dept_name;` is in fact `AND student.dept_name = student.dept_name;` and therefore you basically wrote `WHERE student.tot_cred > 100 AND TRUE;`

Comment: @fancyPants how would I go about checking to see if the student dept name = instructor dept name, would I have to do a select in it?